# Player getting kicked from Minecraft server the moment player gets their inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, aternos

Let me try and explain what is happening as best I can. Bear with me here....

A couple of my friends decided it's time to get a dedicated minecraft server online using one of the free hosting platforms. In this case, Aternos was the selected platform. Note that this server is vanilla.

As for why we don't host our own private server, it's mainly down to our routers not supporting port forwarding or making port forwarding more complex than it needs to be.

We have been playing on the server for some time, but recently, some of my friends have been getting kicked from the server the moment they get their inventory back from the inventory list. They connect just fine, but their inventory causes them to disconnect.

Whenever they disconnect, they get various errors, ranging from a general timed out exception thrown to the host closing the connection. Yet, other players can join and get under way with little to no hassle whatsoever.

Is there anything we can do to the server on Aternos? Or maybe change the settings on the client to help the situation? Anything at all?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? Like just turning it off and turning it on?

Comment: I have. Many times actually. But no luck.

Comment: Do you have access to the server? Some corrupted items can cause anything that loads them to be buggy. And if that's a player, they get kicked.

Comment: I do have access to the server settings, as well as the console and the log of the server. I can control various items, like gamemode forcing and difficulty from a toggle menu, and can run commands in the console, like /say and what have you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's their inventory causing a disconnect, I would delete the player nbt data from the world file. That does cause the inventory data to be lost, but it's hopefully better than not being able to play at all.

As for your not being able to host locally problem, take a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com). It's a port tunneling service, so you can set it up, tunnel tcp 25565, and you'll be able to connect to the IP it gives you.